# Multiple Select Statements

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to create a list of items in which every fourth item in the list is an item that is on from New York and On Sale.  The rest of the items in the list are the items that are from New York no matter if they are on sale or not.

How can I properly use two select statements to break the list up into the order that I want?  Below is what I'm using now.  It creates a list of paragraphs but does not understand what the variables `$article` and `$article2` are.

```
<ul>

<?
    $sort = id;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Catalog` WHERE state = 'New York' and in_stock = 'yes' ORDER BY $sort";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `Catalog` WHERE state = 'New York' and sale_item = 'yes' ORDER BY $sort ";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

    $i = 0;

    while ( $article = mysql_fetch_array($result) || $article2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2) ) { 

        if ($i == 0) {
            echo '<li>This item number is on sale:'.article2[id]. '</li>';
                $i++;       
        } else if ($i == 3) {
                echo '<li>This item number is regular price'.article[id]. '</li>';
                $i = 0;
        } else {
            echo '<li>This item number is regular price'.article[id].'</li>';
            $i++;
        }
    }
    ?>  

</ul>
```

Based on Dave's suggestion I'm trying it this way.  But php still doesn't know how to interpret $itemsOnSale or $items.

```
<ul>
<?   
$items = array();
$itemsOnSale = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Catalog` WHERE state = 'New York' AND in_stock = 'yes' ORDER BY $sort";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

    if ( $row['sale_item'] == 'yes' ) {
        $itemsOnSale[] = $row;  
    } else {
        $items[] = $row;
    }

        if ($i == 0) {
               echo '<li>This item number is on sale:'.$itemsOnSale[id]. '</li>';
               $i++;       
        } else if ($i == 3) {
             echo '<li>This item number is regular price'.$items[id]. '</li>';
             $i = 0;
        } else {
             echo '<li>This item number is regular price'.$items[id].'</li>';
             $i++;
        }

}

  ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

A better method would be to pull all items in a single query, store them in separate arrays, then reference them as necessary.  In its current form your second query pulls sale items but doesn't check to see if they are in stock.

```
$items = array();
$itemsOnSale = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Catalog` WHERE state = 'New York' AND in_stock = 'yes' ORDER BY $sort";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
    if ( $row['sale_item'] == 'yes' ) {
        $itemsOnSale[] = $row;  
    } else {
        $items[] = $row;
    }
}
```

Then construct your HTML list, pulling an array item from $itemsOnSale every 4th loop.

Comment: That seems to be the right idea but still not getting any values.  I've edited my original post to show what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you omitted the $ in front of your variable names:

`echo '<li>This item number is regular price'.article[id].'</li>';`
should be
`echo '<li>This item number is regular price'.$article[id].'</li>';`

As an aside, it looks like you're trying to use what's called MARS -- Multiple Active Result Sets.  Not all database drivers support this.

Comment: Oops! I've added $ to the variable names.  That part I understand.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of your problems:

```
while ( $article = mysql_fetch_array($result) || $article2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2) ) {
```

If a result is found from `$result`, the condition will be met and `$article2` never gets populated. You should re-think the flow of your `while` loop.

You can try something like

```
while ( $article = mysql_fetch_array($result) && $article2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2) ) {
```

but this will finish once either `$article1` or `$article2` is empty. However you can add another `while` loop afterwards with just

```
while( $article = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) { // keep posting regular items }
```

but there's a chance you may have more sale items than regular items (and everything wouldn't get posted.) There's lots of ways to do this.

Also, you have to reference variables using `$`.

```
echo '<li>This item number is on sale:'.$article2['id']. '</li>';
```

You also had an extra closing bracket in your original code, check your parsing.

Comment: Added $ to the variables, thanks.  Still not sure how I could rewrite the while loop.

Comment: I've made some edits, but @Dave has a better approach to your problem. Trying to juggle the result set of two queries on the fly is a rather awkward approach.

Comment: Daves approach does seem right but I'm still not getting results.  Edited my original post to show what I'm doing now.